# How to make C function wait efficiently for Qthread to finish work?

Tags: qt

I have an interesting problem. Working on a C++ project with Qt. Cross-plat project but developing on Win.

I have a C style callback function. It needs to be C style, I have no choice about it.
The work done in that C style callback function is significant and time sensitive. Therefore I have some Qthread threads help with the workload.

I am not using the run scheme with Qt thread, rather I use QThreads as explained at the bottom of the QThread docs. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qthread.html#wait

For the sake of clarity, I am using QThread as such:

```
QThread *thread = new QThread;
Worker *worker = new Worker;
worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

The threads are made at start of application and are fed with QMetaObject::invokeMethod.

The challenge is to not have the C callback function do "anything" (in an efficient way) until the QThread threads have finished their work.  I'd like to make the callback function wait in such a way that it does not compete for the cpu with the worker threads (so no busy dummy loop). I could also use something like sleep() but this is not efficient because if the threads finish 'early' there will be wasteful sleeping. I thought of sending a signal from the workers but the problem is that my callback is a C function so I don't see how it can catch a Qt signal.

Comment: Can`t you wrap C-function with Qt class and catch signal there?

Comment: No, I can't.  The C function is not just a C function, it is a callback function. Part of a lib. I can't change its nature, I can only implement its body. I have no power over what/who calls the callback, i need to keep it a C callback function.

Answer (score 2):

The question is quiet old, but it came up in "related questions". And as this question is interesting and the answer can be useful to Qt users, i've decided to give a detailed answer.

To do wait on a function in a different QThread to finish, multiple strategies are possible:

1. Use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`.
2. Use a naive `while(anAtomicBoolean){}` loop.
3. Use a somewhat more clever `while(anAtomicBoolean){QThread::yieldCurrentThread();}` loop.
4. Use a `QWaitCondition`.
5. Use a `QSemaphore`.

Strategies 2 and 3 look like bad ideas as the waiting thread will have to be active while waiting to check the loop condition. Strategy 3 has however the advantage to release CPU time for other threads and processes.

The 3 other strategies have the advantage of putting the thread to rest while waiting and should be quite equivalent. However solution 1 and 4 does not allow you (or at least easily) to run multiple workers in different threads at the same time. So the best solution would be to go with semaphores.

```
QSemaphore semaphore(2)
worker1.sem = &semaphore;
worker2.sem = &semaphore;
semaphore.acquire(2);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&worker1, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&worker2, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
semaphore.acquire(2); // each worker release(1) when done
semaphore.release(2);
```

To prove my claim I have made a little benchmark (I will make the code available later if someone is interested). I used `QueryThreadCycleTime()` to get the number of cycle consumed by the waiting thread. Like this:

```
QueryThreadCycleTime(hThread, &start);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&worker, "doWork", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
QueryThreadCycleTime(hThread, &stop);
```

The benchmark results are presented in the graph below:
[image: Result graph]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, consider such aproach. Let your callback function do nothing except setting some flag (or incrementing some counter) that is global and shows if (or how many times) your function was called. Then imlement class inherited from QObject (to have slots). You subscribe it to thread finished signal. When signal is emitted you just call another function (with logic of your callback-function) so much times it was called by lib. Will it work?

Comment: It sounds like using hammer to put a coin into a piggy bank

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like this but it satisfies the requirement "I'd like to make the callback function wait in such a way that it does not compete for the cpu with the worker threads (so no busy dummy loop)."

Comment: Thanks but this won't work because the callback was already called to begin with by an outside source (the OS)... this is the catalyst for everything and I would still need a way to block that callback function from finishing and returning before the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have thread "in hand", and you're completly sure that thread will quit itself after finishing work.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#wait

BUT!

If you don't want your thread to quit, and just want to wait until worker emit some singal you may do something like that:

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect(worker, SIGNAL(workFinished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
loop.exec();
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want the threads to die because making new threads is expensive. How would this work when you have more than 1 worker?  It seems to me that after one of the workers is done, the event loop terminates.

Comment: Then you need to create some "pool" object for yourself, that will know about all workers, and keep the track of them. It may use QEventLoop aproach itself and just check if all workers finished